# How to change Postgres database username from inside the pod?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I want to change my Postgres database username and password for the running pod.

I am able to change the password but how to change the username?

Comment: `CREATE user username` ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/user-manag.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the pod:

```sh
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash
```

Run psql

```
# psql
psql>
```

Create the user:

```sql
CREATE USER name CREATEUSER;
ALTER USER name WITH PASSWORD 'your-password';
```

or simply run [`createuser`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/app-createuser.html) from the pod:

```
# createuser --aduser name
```